# How to find the angles of a trapezoid

Tags: angle

The perimeter of a trapezoid is 5 and the lengths of its sides are integers.  What are the smallest two angles of the trapezoid.

The perimeter is 5 so I get 1*2+1*1+2*1 as the sides.  But how do I find out the angles?

Comment: Draw it with a base of length 2 and a top of length 1, then drop an altitude from the top left vertex and another from the top right vertex. Now determine the dimensions of the two triangles you just drew by using symmetry.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

$AD=1$ and $AF=\frac12$, so $m\angle A=\frac\pi3$.